# Changing the default tab in the TelerikTabStrip

Tags: blazor

I am doing app on Blazor and using TelerikTabStrip for my menu. I have four pages in order 1 2 3 4. By default it loads page 1 but I need to load page 2, however not change the order of pages. So by default, I want to load page 2 not page 1. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ActiveTabIndex` parameter:

```
<TelerikTabStrip @bind-ActiveTabIndex="@_activeTabIndex">
   ... 
</TelerikTabStrip>

@code {
    private int _activeTabIndex = 2;
}
```

https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/tabstrip/active-tab-index